# How do you earn coins in Worms: Reloaded?

Tags: worms-reloaded

In Worms:Reloaded you can earn coins from the tutorials and by playing single player campaign.
These Coins allow you to unlock additional weapons and other features in the shop.

**How many coins does each level earn you?** (and are there more ways to get coins?)

---

**Edit:** Bounty for the one that posts the individual values for each level, or the values for the levels that are different from the standard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I've just completed Campaign level 30 now, and can say that:

> Campaign levels 28-29 earn 20 each.
>   Campaign Level 30 earns **1000**.

A reliable friend, who's a little ahead, tells me:

> Campaign Levels 31-35 earn nothing, and cost 100 each to unlock.

And taken from [here](http://worms.wikia.com/wiki/Category:Reloaded_missions), this is (some of!) the rest:

> Campaign Levels 1-5 and 7-9 earn 20 each
>   Campaign Level 6 earns 100

Still leaves 10-27, <strike>and the tutorials</strike>, unaccounted for...

Tutorials (just quickly ran through):

> Tutorials 1 and 2 earn 20 each
>   Tutorial 3 earns 60

Comment: now only those unaccounted levels... and you have earned the bounty

Comment: seems like every 6th level earns you 100

Comment: @Alex so that's 6,12,18,24? Rest 20? I'll edit it into my answer, so it's complete, once you've confirmed.

Answer (score 2):

I'm about halfway through the campaign. Most earn you 20, but I've hit 3 or 4 that have been worth 100.

Answer (score 1):

The number of coins varies from level to level, in theory based on difficulty, but in reality (in my experience), it's completely arbitrary. Between the campaign, the tutorial, and the various other single player content, getting enough coins to unlock everything is not a problem and can be done with 4-6 hours of effort.